# Program not parsing the <a> tag

Tags: python-3.x

I want to parse out the highlighted a tag,from which i want the href link 
- shown in [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROpVM.png)

This is the code I am using

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iqjy9UqKKuo&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDc-3szzjeP6N6b0aDrrKyL-').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')

matchDescription = soup.find('a', class_='yt-simple-endpoint')

print(matchDescription.get('href'))
```

But it is giving error in the output, what is the thing i am doing wrong

Error :- 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get' - for last line of the program

Comment: The *Elements* tab shows the browser DOM *as the browser currently has it*, not the HTML that was loaded. Both HTML standands and running JavaScript code can and does alter the loaded and parsed HTML after the fact, so you **can't count on the Elements tab to show you what will be served to your script**.

Comment: So in your case, the HTML served *doesn't have a `<a class="yt-simple-endpoint">` element* to parse.

Comment: how to get the href link then

Comment: Isn't that link not exactly the same from what you already used to load the page, only with `&index=0` added?

Comment: You can use a project like [`requests-html`](http://html.python-requests.org/) to run a local headless browser to load and execute the Javascript attached to a page and then parse the resulting page structure from there. Overkill in most cases however. I'd look if Youtube offers a proper API to give you the same information without having to scrape their public-facing web UI.

Comment: They do. Youtube has an excellent free api.